# Experience Explorer not showing personalization

Tags: experience-editor, personalization

Having an intermittent issue with Experience Explorer not showing personalizations on a standalone Sitecore 10.2 local dev instance.

It's mostly not working, but has worked twice in the last two days without me knowingly making any changes.

When I try to use the Exp Explorer to demonstrate personalization for countries, it's not working.
I recorded a video, so you can see what happens: https://youtu.be/TKTU64FMYgE

I'll also explain:

1. I have two components setup with personalization rules that change the content based on the country. If the country is Canada, it will display a different data source than default, and yet another for Europe.
2. When I open Exp Explorer and select the country, as soon as I hit the Apply button,
3. the "Viewer" menu from the right side disappears from the right side
   and appears minimized on the left over the "Settings" menu (regardless of it's previous state)
4. then it slides across the screen (expanding as it does until it
   reaches the right side of the screen and then it returns to it's
   previous state.
5. While that happens, the left side "Settings" menu options all collapse and then the "Visitor Information" menu option opens back up.

All of that happens in less than 1 second.

In the log file the following entry can then be found:

```
7372 21:32:22 ERROR Cannot finish Analytics page tracking
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: CurrentPage
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EndAnalytics.SetRobotSessionTimeOut.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EndAnalytics.EndAnalyticsPipeline.Run()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.HttpRequest.EndAnalytics.Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
```

Comment: Do you see any browser console errors while on the experience explorer?

Comment: No browser errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unchecking "Track effect of personalization of this component". I have experienced in past that this would interfere with applying personalization rule.

Read more about this feature here [two-great-new-features-marketers-sitecore-xp-93-petr-anderle](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/two-great-new-features-marketers-sitecore-xp-93-petr-anderle/)

Comment: Marking as answer because this answer solved my problem. If another reader has this error and needs that feature, this will not solve their problem.